# Sort the list of strings after string data was added to the list and add method returns void

Tags: linq, sorting, generic-list

I saw a few similar questions here and most of the answers shows exactly what I did, however it does not help me in my situation.

That's what I have:

I have a number of dates that I add to the List of strings.

```
List<string> DateList { get; set; }

DateList = new List<string>();
DateList.AddRange(CashDataList.Select(d => d.RequestedDate.ToLongDateString()).Distinct().ToList());

DateList.AddRange(CheckDataList.Select(d => d.RequestedDate.ToLongDateString()).Distinct().ToList());

DateList.AddRange(CryptDataList.Select(d => d.RequestedDate.ToLongDateString()).Distinct().ToList());
```

After I added all the dates to my `list` I select unique dates:

```
DateList = DateList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Now, I have the `List<string>` that contains all my dates which I need to display on my UI in `ascending` order.

To do that I want to modify my logic to sort my `list`:

```
DateList = DateList.Sort();
```

However, I'm getting the warning that tells me

> "Cannot implicitly convert type void to
>   System.Collection.Generic.List"

I did  some research and found out that `AddRange` method returns `void`, that's why I have a warning like that.

What is the right way to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can order the list using LINQ:

```
DateList = DateList.OrderBy(q => q);
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but it did not sort: `DateList = DateList.Distinct().OrderBy(q => q).ToList()`

Comment: Ofc it does. `new List<string> { "B", "C", "A","B" }.Distinct().OrderBy(q => q).ToList();` will select unique values from the list and order them alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem.

I had to change to

```
List<string> DataList to List<DateTime>
DateList.AddRange(CashDataList.Select(d => d.RequestedDate).Distinct().ToList());
```

So, my DateList would contain DateTime objects that I can sort. I was not able to sort strings.

And then, in my UI logic, I converted DateTime dates to `ToLongDateString` format.

That solution worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you didn't look up `List<>.Sort`. If you had you would discover it sorts the `List` in-place, and does not have a return value (i.e. returns `void`).

So, instead of

```
DateList = DateList.Sort();
```

you just needed

```
DateList.Sort();
```